# wicket: Dropdownchoice

Tags: wicket

i have two dropdowns using same model and sets the value into it. Dropdown1 will visible on screen always and Dropdown2, will be visible for only one particular option choosen in Dropdown1. and i am making an query to the DB based on the selections in dropdowns.

But when i have both the dropdown first and then hide the second one, The value already set but the Dropdown2 is still avalible in my model, and making my query to fetch improper data.

So can any one suggest me an idea, how to set the value to null for the attribute which is actually set but dropdown2, if dropdown2 is inVisible.

(i tried to set the ModelObject to null, when making the dropdown2 invisible (using AjaxFormComponentupdateBehavior), but when i make the dropdown2, visible again, it returns null,even if i make any selection in it)

Comment: What is the model attached to dropdown2? If it is a PropertyModel, just set the property to null.

Comment: Do you also disable the hidden drop down list? `setVisible()` and `setEnabled()` are two different things.

Comment: This will be much easier to answer if you post some of the code involved so that we can see the relations between your dropdowns and your models.

Comment: Agree with above. Need to see some code to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a LoadableDetachableModel ? try to explicitly detach model from that dropdown on setHide event. I did not try it though.